# Convert Stoplight OpenAPI 3.1 to 3.0

Tags: azure, swagger, openapi, stoplight

I have a use case where I need to covert OpenAPI from 3.1 to 3.0 due to a compatibility issue with Azure. Has anyone worked on this use case? Your help will be appreicated

Comment: [Missing "Convert to OpenAPI 3" command in the online editor https://editor.swagger.io](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/3055) and [Revert default OpenAPI version to 3.0.0](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/pull/1052)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apimatic, I used it for 2.0 -> 3.1 and it worked pretty good, It works also for 3.1 -> 3.0

Here is presentation : https://www.apimatic.io/blog/2021/09/migrating-to-and-from-openapi-3-1/

Go to the interesting part 'Transforming OpenAPI 3.0 Files to OpenAPI 3.1 via APIMatic'

[Transforming OpenAPI 3.0 Files to OpenAPI 3.1 via APIMatic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1mFg.png)